# Consumir un API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo este codigo de una API que estoy haciendo al consumila me muestra un error que dice:

"no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

no se si me hace falta agregar algo a los codigos.

Imagen de los codigos que estoy usando no se si me hace falta algo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Orcas bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomiendo hagas el [tour] del sitio para ver como funciona y también revisar [ask], para formular mejor tus preguntas porque de esa manera puedes conseguir mayor cantidad de ayuda, te recomiendo ademas copies el código a la pregunta para una mejor visualizacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algun elemento (o todos) de `@articles` es un arreglo, por lo que el método `[]` aplicado en `article` espera un número, sin embargo tu estás pasando una cadena de texto:

```
<%= article["image_url"] %>
```

Para arreglarlo debes verificar la estructura que está devolviendo el API (i.e. imprime el contendio de `@articles`) para que puedas dar el tratamiento adecuado a cada elemento.

Generalmente, con `HTTParty.get` (considerando la respuesta actual de tu API), harías algo así:

```
@articles = HTTParty.get(...).body[:articles]

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= article["image_url"] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: si muchas gracias ya lo pude solucionar era un error en la estructura del array

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando un string como un number.

Esto puede suele pasar cuando querés hacer una operación matemática con un string

ej:

```
 "no soy un número" + 4
```

Fijate si no tienes campos strings en los params que creés que son numbers